# how to save data from arduino into .YUV extension file?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, yuv

I am getting some data from Arduino mega serially thorough `serial.write`, I want to save that data into some file with `.yuv` extension. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a program that connects to a `COM` port and reads the serial data in from the Arudino and saves to to a file stream. I have a sample project coded in C# [here](https://github.com/StefanBossbaly/Kane). It includes both the Arduino program and the program that runs on the computer. For reading serial data in C# look at the [SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You don't have to use C#, you can use any programming language supported by the operating system on the computer.

Comment: its there any terminal program that i can use ? like realTerm or hypererminal